# How to calculate the percentage of day in a month (except weekends and US public holiday) based on the date inputed in excel?

Tags: excel, date, formula

[image]

Hi all, I have an input of date (attendance) as shown in the screenshot above. I want to calculate the percentage of these input out of the whole month except weekend and public holidays in US, how should I able to acheive that?

So for November 2020, there are 21 weekdays in total, after minus two public holiday (Veteran and Thanks giving day) total will be 19 weekdays so the desired output will be 4/19 = 21%. Any idea how should do this in excel? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try on below formula-

```
=COUNTA(B4:B7)/(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(DATE(2020,11,1),EOMONTH(DATE(2020,11,1),0),1)-2)
```

[image]